# Why should you run cd . before doing anything?

Tags: directory

In [this compilation of sysadmin horrors](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/horror.txt), one of the authors writes, as a rule of thumb:

> Always do a `cd .` before doing anything.

Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You don't.

At least not just like that. The preceding line in the quoted document is of importance:

> - Set up your prompt to do a `pwd` everytime you cd.
> - Always do a `cd .` before doing anything.

This way, you as the operator verify your current working dir before doing anything of importance, as it's printed out with each change. `cd .` doesn't make any sense otherwise.

This "verification" is a good thing, and you should adapt a form of it. A more (IMHO) common variation of this theme is to **always** print out the working dir at the prompt.

Comment: It is probably better to think of this as "always type 'pwd' before doing anything important to make sure you are in the directory you think you are"

Comment: Why not just do a `pwd` before doing anything?

Comment: Actually, it does have a use. If you've gone into a directory via a symbolic link, and the link then gets deleted and re-created elsewhere, such as during a server deployment where versions are controlled with a symlink to "current_release", then doing `cd .` would change the actual underlying directory that you are in.

Comment: +1 for "**always** print out the working dir at the prompt." That is what I do.

Comment: @Stewart Unfortunately this won't help if the symbolic link changes *after* `cd .` but *before* doing anything else. It just reduces the likelihood of being in the wrong directory, but doesn't solve the general problem. Unless you switch to the real directory using something like `cd $(readlink -f .)` given that you actually want to stay there.

Answer (score 18):

If the current working directory of your shell is removed, it is possible to lose data.

For example,

```
$ pwd
/home/user/test
$ rmdir /home/user/test
$ pwd
/home/user/test
$ some_command | tee command.log
tee: command.log: No such file or directory
<long output>
```

The output of `some_command` was not written to the disk.

Typing `cd .` before running a command would reveal the problem.

```
$ pwd
/home/user/test
$ rmdir /home/user/test
$ cd .
$ pwd
.
```

If the current working directory directory was removed and re-created, typing `cd .` would "refresh" the reference to that directory.

```
$ ls
foo bar ljz
$ pwd
/home/user/test
$ rmdir /home/user/test
$ mkdir /home/user/test
$ pwd
/home/user/test
$ ls
$ cd .
$ ls 
foo bar ljz
```

Answer (score 13):

I think it's more important to show your current directory.

On every linux server, I modify the prompt in `/etc/bashrc` by changing "W" to "w".

```
 [ "$PS1" = "\\s-\\v\\\$ " ] && PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "
```

to

```
 [ "$PS1" = "\\s-\\v\\\$ " ] && PS1="[\u@\h \w]\\$ "
```

---

The effect of this is:

```
[root@xt include]#
```

versus

```
[root@xt /usr/src/spl-0.6.1/include]#
```

Comment: is `PS1` bash-specific?

Comment: I think so... It's all I use.

Comment: Your changes might get lost with the next system upgrade, tho.

Comment: @ott-- The stick it your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` as well as updating `/etc/skel/.profile`